# Handleclick is being called twice in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a modal which is called when a button is clicked. each modal has a close button also

```html
<div class=" flex border" x-data="{ modelOpen: false }"
    @@click="handleClick($event, @Model.ProductId)">
<script>
  // Do something with the productId
  function handleClick(event, productId) {
    console.log("vfg");
  }
</script>
```

It is also being called when closed button is pressed ? why it is so?

```html
<button @@click="modelOpen = false" type="button"
    class="absolute right-4 top-4 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 sm:right-6 sm:top-8 md:right-6 md:top-6 lg:right-8 lg:top-8">
  <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
  <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Is the `<button>` inside the `<div x-data>`? If so, then that would be reason.

Comment: ok that was almost the reason.